# Copy the file directory and files using Gulp

Tags: javascript, task, gulp

I am newbie in Gulp.
What I am trying to do is copy the full directory and its files to another folder. The source has this structure source-submodule > app_A > www. I only want to copy the www folder and its subdirectories and files inside. The destination is in the same level of source-submodule so it will be call dest-submodule > App_A > [files and subfolders of www].

Below is my sample gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.src('./source-submodule/app_A/www/*.*', {base: '.'})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest-submodule/App_A/'));
```

Above is working, can somebody point me to the right direction?

Thanks,

Comment: What you got so far? Could you print the gulp output in there?

Comment: After fixing the syntax problem (oops!). It did copy all the files but not the folder inside it.
How can I copy all the folders as well?

Comment: Please, could you print your terminal output?

Comment: [16:20:02] Using gulpfile ~.../www/gulpfile.js
[16:20:02] Starting 'default'...
[16:20:02] Finished 'default' after 52 μs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested here and it's working fine, also I've created a Gist for you: https://gist.github.com/felipekm/84ab012338c024894b14

Here's the code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var paths = {
  scripts: ['app/scripts/**/*.js'],
  html: ['app/index.html', '!app/test.html'], 
  dist: ['dist/']
};

gulp.task('default', function(){
  gulp.src(paths.scripts.concat(paths.html)).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist));
});
```

The "!" operator means the type of file that will not be copied.
Hope this helps.

Comment: My pleasure mate, just make it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I made it work and the files get copied.

   var folderstruct = [
 './sub-apps/app1/www/*.*',
 './sub-apps/app1/www/bwipp/*.*',
 './sub-apps/app1/www/config/*.*',
 './sub-apps/app1/www/css/*.*'
 ];

    gulp.src(folderstruct, {base: './sub-apps/app1/'})
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./target-apps/app1/'));




My challenge right now is.. I do not want to list the folder. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Create another question so I help you! :)

Comment: Thanks! I got it.
I used the     './sub-apps/app1/www/**/*.*' and then it works! :-)